# Unable to add tooltip for titles in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am facing issues with adding custom tooltip to the titles in charts created using highcharts library. When I try to select the title dom using jquery and append the tooltip content to the title, highcharts is not rendering the html content which I am trying to add.Could someone help with adding tooltip.

I tried something as below, it didn't work.

```
title: {
    text: 'Plan Duration',
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'Testing';
        }
    },
},
```

similarly, I tried by accessing DOM element and appending tooltip content

```
($('.highcharts-title')[1]).tooltip({
    content: 'TOOLTIP CONTENT'
});
```

both the techniques failed

Comment: Please provide the HTML/JS/CSS sample which you have worked so far in JSFiddle.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly are you trying to do? Tooltip appears only when you hover over a series or point. It is not designed to display on hover on title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tootips should be defined in `series`.

```
series: [{
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span>Custom text including HTML tags... Whatever.</span>'
  },
  // Other properties...
```

[Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat)

Comment: I rolled back the "community approved" edit. -- That edit is a QUESTION added to my answer. Unacceptable, from my understanding.